# Unable to undraw on a transparent surface in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I'm attempting to create a method to essentially erase a drawing on a surface. I have the functionality working for an surface that contains a png, but when I use the same method to remove a surface that is drawn on by `pygame.draw.lines()` it is not erasing.

The major difference between the two surfaces is one is transparent and other is not. I think I may not understand fully how pygames transparent surfaces work.

Not working `undraw()`:

```
class MovementComponent(AbstactComponent):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        game_surfaces = GameSurfaces() #singleton class that rerenders all of the surfaces in order
        self.movement_surface = game_surfaces.movement_surface
        self.path_surface = pg.Surface(self.movement_surface.get_size(), pg.SRCALPHA)
        self.path_surface.set_alpha(150)

    def draw_movement(self):
        if len(self.queue()) >= 2:
            tile_centers = []
            for tile in self.queue():
                tile_centers.append(tile.center_pixel)

            pg.draw.lines(
                self.path_surface, 
                self.character.color, 
                False, tile_centers, 3
            )
            
            self.movement_surface.blit(self.path_surface, (0,0))

    def undraw_movement(self):
        empty = pg.Color(0,0,0,0)
        self.path_surface.fill(empty)
        self.movement_surface.blit(self.path_surface, (0,0))
```

The working undraw in another component:

```
class SpriteComponent(AbstactComponent):
    NORMAL_SIZE = (55,55)

    def __init__(self, image: pg.image):
        surfaces = GameSurfaces()
        self.char_surface = surfaces.character_surface
        self.pixel_pos: (int,int) = None

        self.standard_image = pg.transform.scale(image, self.NORMAL_SIZE)
        self.empty = pg.Color(0,0,0,0)

    def draw(self, pixel_pos: (int, int)):
        self.pixel_pos = pixel_pos
        top_left_pixel = self.get_topleft_pos(pixel_pos)
        self.char_surface.blit(self.standard_image, top_left_pixel)

    def undraw(self, pixel_pos: (int, int)=None):
        pixel_pos = pixel_pos if pixel_pos else self.pixel_pos
        top_left_pixel = self.get_topleft_pos(self.pixel_pos)
        rect_to_clear = pg.Rect(top_left_pixel, self.NORMAL_SIZE)
        self.char_surface.fill(self.empty, rect_to_clear)
```

Comment: If you have a new question you have to [Ask a public question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) again, but don't change this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transparent `Surface` is blended with the background. When deleting, however, you want to cover the background completely. Therefore you have to make the `Surface` temporarily opaque again for the deletion. If you call [`set_alpha`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_alpha) with the argument `None`, the previously set transparency is canceled again:

```py
class MovementComponent(AbstactComponent):
    # [...]

    def undraw_movement(self):
        empty = pg.Color(0,0,0,0)
        self.path_surface.fill(empty)
        self.path_surface.set_alpha(None)
        self.movement_surface.blit(self.path_surface, (0,0))
        self.path_surface.set_alpha(150)
```